# Java OOP strategy

Tags: java, swing, oop

I have a project called Visual Data Structures. I have a OOP design like this.

```
Class VisualDataStructures extends JFrame
Class ControlPanel extends JPanel
Class CodePanel extends JPanel
```

The `Class VisualDataStructures` has the main. This class has an instances of Class ControlPanel and CodePanel.

The `Class ControlPanel` has `JMenuItem` named "Load" inside a `JMenuBar`.

The `Class CodePanel` has a `JTextArea`.

Question:
I need to have a actionlistener for the `JMenuItem` named "load" inside the class `ControlPanel`. When the load is clicked, the user will enter the directory of the file, then the file will be loaded and displayed at the `JTextArea` of the `CodePanel`.

Do i need to pass the object CodePanel which is instantiated from the VisualDataStructures to the `ControlPanel` in order for me to use the object and then modify the value of the JTextArea?

Does anybody know a better approach for this? Thanks.

Comment: Look up "MVC" pattern - your application has a model which gets bound to the UI elements so you can change the model and the model propagates the changes to the UI.

Comment: I had thought about that too. I didn't really know if it is THE better approach. But i will try. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulJabines There is no THE better approach in general. Google MVVM, MVP, MV? as well: Which approach is most appropriate differs from use case to use case

Comment: i dont know about that MVVM MVP and MV. I will google it. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to answer that question without seeing the actual code, but I will still try. Maybe if you could share your code somehow, via Github, Bitbucket, as a Gist or in a Pastebin, I could give a better answer. It then might also be better to do that on CodeReview stackexchange instead of StackOverflow.

In general, I find it a bit suspicious that there are so many `extends` from GUI parent classes. *Usage by extension* can be a bit of an *anti-pattern*. It might lead to seemingly simple code in tiny applications in the first place, but in the long run it tends to obfuscate source code because it encourages a mix of business logic and UI. It's a misunderstanding that extension is the core of OOP. It's not. Polymorphic abstraction in order to decouple and invert key dependencies, that's the core of OOP. Extension is just a nice and convenient goody on top of that, and it's overused.

Speaking of that, you might have heard of *MVC - Model View Controller*. This is the typical pattern for UIs to keep things separate.

You do not want the `ActionListener` that reacts on the `load` action to directly know the `CodePanel`, for a dependency like that this is too concrete. You want to have an abstraction in-between, like an interface, and refer to that interface instead of `CodePanel`.

When it comes to `ActionListener` and similar interfaces, you might be interested in upgrading to Java 8, if you haven't done yet. Interfaces like `ActionListener` with just one abstract method are implicitly functional interfaces, which means you can use lambdas or method references.

In general, I think it helps a lot of always keeping in mind the following question: *what if I replace the UI toolkit with a different one?* Even if it's not a use case and would never happen, the decoupling and separation of concerns that you do in order to answer that question lead to more modular, better designs which are easier to understand and maintain. In the end, the question *what if I replace the UI toolkit with a different one?* leads to a design which follows more of the *SOLID principles*.

When dealing with `ActionListener` in Swing, you might want to look at `interface Action` and `abstract class AbstractAction`. They offer very interesting capabilities. Used in the right way, they can simplify code a lot.

Comment: You was faster than me ;). All what you siad is also my choice on UI development.

Comment: sry Very late reply, Very good answer. thanks for the tips on OOP design.